# Does WebStorm Node.js Remote Debug work with Node.js v8 in Docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, webstorm

Using `chrome://inspect` I can access `0.0.0.0:56745` to do debugging,

[image]

But I find debugging in WebStorm a far better experience. I try to create a `Node.js Remote Debug` configuration like this to see if WebStorm supports it:

[image]

There's no response to any breakpoints in the js files.

Can you tell me whether WebStorm supports debugging Docker node inside WebStorm (not via Chrome developer tool) in the latest 2017.2.5 version?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/DockerfileDev.df
    image: web:dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "0.0.0.0:56745:56745"
    expose:
      - "56745"
    entrypoint: ["npm", "run","nodemon" ]
```

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "nodemon": "./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js --inspect=0.0.0.0:56745 --debug-brk index.js"
  },
```

DockerfileDev.df

```
  FROM node:8
  # some other stuff
```

**UPDATE**

The Remote debugger shows it's connecting, but there's nothing in the console, and doesn't pause at breakpoints:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Node.js Remote](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.2/run-debug-configuration-node-js-remote-debug.html) run configuration can only be used when debugging with TCP-based Protocol (Node.js < 7.x).

To remotely debug application with Chrome Debugging Protocol (with `--inspect`/`--inspect-brk`, Node.js 7+), you need using [Chromium Remote](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.2/run-debug-configuration-chromium-remote.html?utm_campaign=WS&utm_content=2017.2&utm_medium=help_link&utm_source=from_product) run configuration

Comment: Hope the remote debugger will support node.js > 7.x someday.

Answer (score 0):

After spending days trying to figure out what the problem was, I found that I needed to set the remote debug host to:
**localhost**

then, make sure to update the "default" machine in Virtual Box to **forward** port:
56745 (NAT)

This way, I figured, webstorm connects to the container debugger through your host machine. At least that's the way I got Nodejs v8 to work.

Good luck!